# JSON Array Restful to textarea

Tags: javascript, json

I am working in some code for school and has spend a couple of days looking thru post's but can't find a solution, this is actually my first post and welcome everyone who take the time to help!

I am coding a restful JSON API which I can send the data to the web service, however when I tried to read it and send the data to a textarea, I either get [object, Object] or a 0 (which I think is the index for the array generated from the json).

This is my code for the read function:

```
function cargarInfo(){
    $.get("http://localhost:8080/Lec09/miApi/acciones", function(data, status){
       var personas = data.personas;

       document.getElementById("info").value = personas;
    });
}
```

When I debug on chrome I can see the Object and the values, I think this is a realy noob question however IDK why I can't figure it out, it is suposed to show the json {nombre:xxxx  apellidos:xxxxx} data

[image]

Comment: Do you try JSON.stringify(data)?

Comment: What do you want to be displayed in the textarea?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JSON.stringify()` to stringify your JSON data:

```
document.getElementById("info").value = JSON.stringify(personas);
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!! it worked, I know it has to be super simple, appreciate your help Sebastian